# выводим таблицу из двух запросов

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Драсте такой вопрос
есть таблица друзей
и есть таблица пользователей
алгоритм такой,

ищем ID пользователей в таблице друзя  (к примеру где статус = 1)
дале вытаскиваем строки из таблицы пользователей где ID равняется ID из таблицы друзей и в которых **сравниваем даты( online.' + 15 min > now() )**
и выводим табицу которые прошли проверку
Немогу понять как реализовать чтобы не писать +100500 запросов к базе данных 
и не нагружать бд

Comment: Дайте название таблиц и структуру, будет проще общаться а так делайте SELECT ... FROM друзья LEFT JOIN пользователи ON (друзья.id = пользователи.id) WHERE друзья.online = 1 или другие ограничения из вопроса не понять.

Comment: вот к чему я ришол со своими знаниями <br>
<? $Result = mysqli_query($CONNECT, 'SELECT `id`, `uid`, `inid`, `date` FROM `friend` WHERE (`uid` = '.$_SESSION['id'].' AND `inactive` = 1 AND `unactive` = 1) OR (`inid` = '.$_SESSION['id'].' AND `unactive` = 1 AND `inactive` = 1) ORDER BY `date` DESC ');
while ($Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result)) {
 if ($Row['uid'] == $_SESSION['id']) $Friend = $Row['inid'];
 else $Friend = $Row['uid']; $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc( mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT `id`, `name`, `family`, `avatar`, `town` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = $Friend AND `online` > now() ") );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тяжело понять структуру таблиц

```
SELECT friend.id, friend.uid, friend.inid, friend.date, users.id, users.name, users.family, users.avatar, users.town
        FROM 
            friend LEFT JOIN users ON friend.uid=users.id
        WHERE 
            friend.inactive = 1 
            AND friend.unactive = 1
            AND users.online > now()
```

Comment: спасибо это то что нужно! теперь я понл как сделать)